How to parse case-insensitive with lrparsing?
This following example attempt to parse a simplified Delphi language where keywords and variables are case-insensitive.
import sys
import lrparsing
from lrparsing import Keyword, List, Prio, Ref, Token, Tokens, Grammar, TokenRegistry, Some, Choice, Opt, Left, Right, THIS

class DelphiPasParser(lrparsing.Grammar):
    
    Identifier = Token(re="[a-z][a-z0-9_]*", case=False)
    FinalEnd = Token('end.', case=False)
    Unit = Keyword('unit', case=False) + Identifier + Token(';') + FinalEnd
    START = Unit


delphi_code = "Unit MyUnit; end."
parser = DelphiPasParser()
try:
    parse_tree = parser.parse(delphi_code)
except lrparsing.TokenError as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit();
print(DelphiPasParser.repr_parse_tree(parse_tree))

The problem is that Token seems to incorrectly detect similarity:
End. is detected to be a Keyword of Token(re="[a-z][a-z0-9_]*", case=False) but the dot is not in the regex.

Token.re (/[a-z][a-z0-9_]*/, <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='end'>) partially matches None of Keyword 'end.'

And even without that, Unit is not recognized:

("Unrecognised token 'U' at line 1 column 1", 'U', 0, 1, 1)

How to properly parse this ?
